# gsp page with select derived from a previous select Unclosed GSP expression

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy, gsp

new to groovy on grails and struggling with a bit of a bespoke if always requested solution.

I  am trying to create two selects using ajax, one populated with information based on the other. The example I am following is here http://www.grails.org/AJAX-Driven+SELECTs+in+GSP. I am also using scaffold, so I had to use the install-templates command to get the views to manipulate the gsp files. With a bit of tweeking from the template I have a working create view for my selects to be built. But inputing these selects as specified in the tutorial results in an error I can't work out

```
Stack trace as below :
| Error 2013-01-12 16:11:46,582 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - GrailsTagException occurred when processing request: [GET] /TimeTracker2/time/create
Unclosed GSP expression. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error initializing GroovyPageView
    Line | Method
->>  186 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by GrailsTagException: Unclosed GSP expression
->>   33 | doFilter  in \grails-app\views\time\create.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

my GSP is below and you can see that all expressions are closed...... Advice?

```
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <g:set var="entityName" value="\${domainClass.propertyName}" />
    <title>Create Time</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#create-{domainClass.propertyName}" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
    <div class="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="home" href="/TimeTracker2"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
            <li><g:link class="list" action="list"><!--g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /-->Time List</g:link></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="create-{domainClass.propertyName}" class="content scaffold-create" role="main">
        <h1><!--g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /-->Create Time</h1>
        <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>
        <g:hasErrors bean="\${propertyName}">
        <ul class="errors" role="alert">
            <g:eachError bean="\${propertyName}" var="error">
            <li <g:if test="\${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="\${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="\${error}"/></li>
            </g:eachError>
        </ul>
        </g:hasErrors>
        <g:form action="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <fieldset class="form">
                <g:render template="form"/>
                <g:select
                    optionKey="id" optionValue="Project" name="project.name" id="project.name" from="${Project.list()}"
                    onchange="${remoteFunction(
                    controller:'project', 
                    action:'ajaxGetClassifications', 
                    params:'\\'id='\\' + escape(this.value)', 
                    onComplete:'updateClassification(e)')}"
                    ></g:select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="Create" />
            </fieldset>
        </g:form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Put everything for the select on one line

Comment: Also if you are using jQuery, it will be `updateClassification(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Id put the javascript function for the select's onChange event into a separate function, instead of inline in the g:select tag.

Comment: alas no. bare with me this is actually my first crack at javascript, was hoping to avoid it. code now as below, new error method list() cannot be invoked on a null object, when an instance of project and classification exists

Comment: <g:form action="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <fieldset class="form">
     <g:render template="form"/>
     <g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="Project" name="project.name" id="project.name" from="${Project.list()}" onchange="forChange()"></g:select>

Comment: <script language="javascript">
     function forChange(){
     controller:'project', action:'ajaxGetClassifications', params:'\\'id='\\' + escape(this.value)', onComplete:'updateClassification(data)'
     } </script>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
     <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="Create" />
    </fieldset>
   </g:form>

Comment: It's really difficult to read your code in the comments - can you post it somewhere where it's formatted? Or maybe edit your original question and add the new code there?

Answer (score 0):

After working through the issues (and there were many) the answer was providing the correct FULL location of my domain class.

```
    <g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="name" name="project.name" id="project.name" 
from="${timetracker2.Project.list()}" onchange="${remoteFunction(controller:'project', 
                            action:'ajaxGetClassifications', 
                            params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)', 
                            onComplete:'updateClassification(e)')}"
                        ></g:select>
```

My issue now lays with exactly how to persist the information, and how to actually make the second list derive its values from the first. But that's another question for another day.